# Кроссбраузерный Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) для ие

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Может кто-то подсказать, есть ли решение для динозавра IE?

```
Object.prototype.each = function() {
      for (var prop in this) {
if (!this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
this[prop]+=100;
    return this
      }
    }
    var obj = { name: 'Вася', age: 25 };
    obj.each()
    alert(obj.name)
    alert(obj.age)
```

В объекте не меняется 2 значения, а только одно. Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В объекте не меняется 2 значения, а только одно

return за пределы цикла вынесите

Comment: Спасибо Spectre